# how to add file phtml in file phtml magento?

Tags: php, overriding, magento-1.9

I want to show the contents file: frontend \ RWD \ default \ template \ customer / address / edit.phtm
inside the file: frontend \ RWD \ default \ template \ customer / account / dashboard.phtml.
i insert this code into the file dashboard.phtml

```
<?php
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('customer/address/edit.phtml')->toHtml();
echo $block; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct block type for that section is customer/address_edit. So please try the following:

```
<?php
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/address_edit')->setTemplate('customer/address/edit.phtml')->toHtml();
echo $block;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the render "partial views" in this case instead the way you did.

In Magento, the approach is somewhat different. Basically, Magento uses Blocks which are associated with templates in the view, so each page consists of both a block PHP class (they all inherit from Mage_Core_Block_Abstract) and mostly (but there are exceptions) an associated template (phtml file).

To render partials, blocks can have child blocks within them with given child names. From the parent block, you can render the child blocks using getChildHtml($childName). To set variables at the child block, you can use the magic getter and setters, because all block PHP classes ultimately extend from Varien_Object.